# qt how to connect 2D array of QPushButton and return the location

Tags: c++, vector, mapping, qt-creator, signals-slots

I'm new to QT Creator GUI and I'm having a hard time with Signals and Slots. I'm using QT 4.2.1 to make a word search puzzle for practicing

Below is a portion of my code, creating a 2D puzzle using vectors. I tried to use array but the size of the puzzle will be decided by the user. I had a lot of compile errors using array. So I decided to use Vector

I tried some options from this post: [Get index of QPushButton on 2D array QPushButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641306/get-index-of-qpushbutton-on-2d-array-qpushbutton) but they all don't work.

Can you help me to see why the signals and slots are not connected? And is there a way to check if the signal is connected?
I would appreciate any helps and feedback. Thank you!

```
void MainWindow::displayPuzzle(QVector<QVector<QPushButton*>>& button, QVector<QVector<QChar>> puzzle2D){

widget1 = new QWidget;
QGridLayout* l = new QGridLayout;
QSignalMapper mapper;

for (int r = 0; r < puzzle2D.size(); r++) {
    QVector<QPushButton*> vect;
    for (int c = 0; c < puzzle2D[r].size(); c++) {

        //format the button
        vect.push_back(new QPushButton);
        vect.last()->setText(puzzle2D[r][c]);
        vect.last()->setFixedSize(60,60);
        vect.last()->show();
        auto pos = QString{"%1 %2"}.arg(r).arg(c);

        //connect with signals and slots
        mapper.connect(vect.last(), SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(map()));
        mapper.setMapping(vect.last(), pos);

        //add button to layout
        l->addWidget(vect.last(), r, c);
        l->setSpacing(0);
        l->setMargin(0);
        l->setContentsMargins(-1,-1,-1,-1);

    }
    button.push_back(vect);
}
connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), SLOT(puzzleClick(QString)));

widget1->setLayout(l);

}

void MainWindow::puzzleClick(QString text){

    int r = text.split(" ").at(0).toInt();
    int c = text.split(" ").at(1).toInt();

    QMessageBox::information(this, "click:", r + " " + c );

}
```

Comment: Why on heart are you using Qt 4.2? Qt is currently at version 5.8 ...

Comment: Maybe is that you are using Qt Creator version 4.2.1? Which Qt library version is your application linked against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are linking is very complete and useful, I think you should stick with that one. Any suggestion about those methods would be just rewriting the original answer. Maybe you can ask something more **specific** about what you can't understand of those options.

Another solution, not cited in that answer, would be implementing a class extending QPushButton, intercept the clicked() signal and re-emit it with the data you want. The same thing can be obtained with lambda functions in Qt5 and C++11: have a look at this: [qt-custom-qpushbutton-clicked-signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668541/qt-custom-qpushbutton-clicked-signal) the two answers to this questions explain how to do this.

Comment: I used lambda function, but then realized it's the syntax for Qt 5x. That's why I changed to the current method. 
I downloaded QT a few years ago, and the version I'm allowed to download for free is 4.2.1. But let me try to update it and use Lambda function. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works perfectly when I use version 5.8. thank you